# Store Image and Text in one datatype android

Tags: android, list

I would like to know a way to store an image and associated text in something like a List. I tried doing something like this

```
List<NameValuePair>cars = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
 cars.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Hyundai Elantra",Integer.toString(R.drawable.hyundai_elantra)));
```

I know this is wrong but I'm posting it so you get an idea of what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Use a HashMap where you can use the text as key and the image as the value

Comment: Are you looking to display the list in a ListView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the best thing for you would be to create a custom class called `Car` to store each car, and then create an `ArrayList<Car>` to store the data.

Here is what your Car class would look like:

```
public class Car
{
  public String type;
  public int imageID;
  public Car(String t, int i)
  {
    type = t;
    imageID = i;

  }

  public String toString()
  {
    return type + " " + String.valueOf(imageID);
  }
}
```

Then you would declare the ArrayList, and add values:

```
ArrayList<Car> carList = new ArrayList<Car>();

carList.add(new Car("Hyundai Elantra", R.drawable.hyundai_elantra));

carList.add(new Car("Lexus RX350", R.drawable.lexus_rx350));
```

Then, you could iterate through the list when you want to populate your UI:

```
for (Car c : carList){

  String s = c.type;
  int image = c.imageID;

  //use the values.......

}
```

Note that you could use this ArrayList as the data source for a custom adapter for displaying the text and images in a ListView, if that's what you're looking to do.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a class named NameValue with Textand Image and you can declare an array list as follows

```
List<NameValue >cars = new ArrayList<NameValue >();
```